# How can this error be? 'Invalid WebP header detected' using Imazen.WebP.SimpleDecoder

Tags: c#-4.0, webp

I have the following code:

```
SimpleDecoder decoder = new SimpleDecoder();
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
Bitmap image = decoder.DecodeFromBytes(fileBytes, fileBytes.Length);

PictureBox pb = new PictureBox
    {
    Size = new Size(100, 100),
    Image = image,
    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
    Tag = filename
    };

FlpThumbnails.Controls.Add(pb);
pb.Refresh();
Application.DoEvents();
```

at the `Bitmap image = decoder.DecodeFromBytes(fileBytes, fileBytes.Length);` I get the exception thrown `System.Exception: 'Invalid WebP header detected'`. However, in my Windows Explorer I can see the image perfectly well.

I am using `Imazen.WebP.SimpleDecoder` to decode the image.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I created a solution.

In his code I did the following:

```
public static Bitmap DecodeFromPointer(IntPtr data, long length)
    {
        int w = 0, h = 0;
        //Validate header and determine size
        if (NativeMethods.WebPGetInfo(data, (UIntPtr)length, ref w, ref h) == 0)
        {
            w = 100;
            h = 100;
            NativeMethods.WebPGetInfo(data, (UIntPtr)length, ref w, ref h);
            //  throw new Exception("Invalid WebP header detected");
        }
```

I commented out the throw new exception, and added the default thumbnail size I am using of 100,100. It still does not show the image but it continues until...

It gets a little further down the file and finds this:

```
//  if (bd.Scan0 != result) throw new Exception("Failed to decode WebP image with error " + (long)result);
```

As you can see I simply commented that line out as well.

And that was all I had to do to get `Imazen.WebP.SimpleDecoder` to not crash on images that I can see in Explorer but not see in my .Net Application. It is true I can still not see the images but the application does not crash anymore.